# Convert POST text output into JSON

Tags: php, json

I am converting POST into JSON and then saving into the table. Somehow my code and query is not working, also I am sending POST output text into the emails as a backup. I have to save missing JSON entries into tables. I have JSON format and I can convert manually POST into JSON but this will be very time consuming and also I have lots of data that need to be save. Is there anyway I can convert POST output text into JSON?

Below is the POST output text that I have to convert into the JSON.

```
Array ( [mc_gross] => 2.00 [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible [address_status] => confirmed [payer_id] => W92W4QGG4DPSE [tax] => 0.00 [address_street] => Street Park [payment_date] => 08:49:32 Oct 01, 2020 PDT [payment_status] => Pending [charset] => windows-1252 [address_zip] => 123456 [first_name] => John [address_country_code] => US [address_name] => Address name [notify_version] => 3.9 [custom] => 14673|2628|0|0 [payer_status] => verified [address_country] => US [address_city] => City [quantity] => 1 [verify_sign] => AYeK0nPD6ny3nwQhXIe-HRLjFsBxAbVcuekfRoqaw421iA6T6-9HuwOZ [payer_email] => ea9ym2967401@exampledomain.com [txn_id] => 7NK31954DJ9775812 [payment_type] => instant [last_name] => Doe [address_state] => State [receiver_email] => info@domain.com [shipping_discount] => 0.00 [insurance_amount] => 0.00 [pending_reason] => unilateral [txn_type] => web_accept [item_name] => US Open 2020 [discount] => 0.00 [mc_currency] => USD [item_number] => 23344 [residence_country] => US [test_ipn] => 1 [shipping_method] => Default [transaction_subject] => [payment_gross] => 2.00 [ipn_track_id] => 53d2891cbb8c1 )
```

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the code. Is it possible can be converted from the code or any tool?

Comment: On SO we help with your code. so give it a try. Converting an array to json is easy.

Comment: I have output of the POST as text in the email, I am not submitting or posting.